# Update references and labels of equations after changing the order

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, chapters

This seems again trivial, but I cannot find any solution to my problem in the questions that have been asked on referencing.

The issue can be explained easily: I am making a document with many equations which are numbered consecutively. All of them are labelled (manually) via `\label` and referenced via `\ref`.
Now let's say I decide to move one of the equations at the beginning of the document to the Appendix. This makes all of the following labels and references too large by exactly 1. 
I cannot believe I have to edit all of them manually? I mean it's possible if you make all the references at the end of your work, but still I wonder if there is a more effective way.

Comment: run the document at least two times to get the labels right!

Comment: @Herbert Are you saying that Tex automatically adjusts the references? Because I I get a wrong order even if I run my document many times. But maybe there is another reason if you are certain that references are updated automatically?

Comment: @TomM as Herbert pointed out, references should be updated automatically, but you'd have to run tex twice to make the updates appear in your final document...  (first run to gather new ref. numbers, second to show them).  If you tried this and it doesn't work, i'd suggest to put a MWE online...

Comment: @long tom Thanks, it worked. At first all have been wrong, but after running the doc twice most of the numbers were correct. The reason not all were correct was my equation somewhere at the end, labelled incorrectly.

Comment: Note that the string you put in the `\label` is unrelated to the printed number, it is just a symbolic name for internal referencing.

Comment: to follow up on david's comment, the ability to rearrange your labeled items is a good reason to assign descriptive labels, not numerical ones.

Comment: Thanks guys. I know that label is untelated to the printout. @barbarabeeton Ok sounds reasonable, but I have so many equations and inbetween calculations which are sometimes numbered as well if they are important, I cannot really name all of them. I want to number them :)

Comment: @David Carlisle After reading your comment again, I realized the problem is not solved yet. I know that the label is unrelated to the printout, however I would actually like to link it, because the printout is always correct with regard to the numbering.
Or in other words, I would like to generate labels that are equal to the sequence in which the equations occur in the document. Doesn't anyone else want this? I am confused :)

Comment: \ref{zzz} generates the same number used in the equation labeled with `\label{zzz}` the internal label `zzz` is just to make that link, it is unrelated to the number used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to label my equations eq1, eq2 etc. in order to remember them (especially if I come back after a delay).  A partial solution is to use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{myeqn}
\newcommand{\eqlabel}{
\stepcounter{myeqn}
\label{eq\arabic{myeqn}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\eqlabel
A=A
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\eqlabel
A\neq B
\end{equation}

If one substitues for $A$ using (\ref{eq1}) into (\ref{eq2})
\end{document}
```

Of course, the references occur randomly and still have to be edited manually.  Then again, I avoid autonumbering in general (it's easier to add than remove).

Comment: Since you're already loading the `mathtools` package (which, in turns, loads the `amsmath` package), you may want to look into using the command `\eqref{...}` instead of `(\ref{...})`. A real advantage to using `\eqref` is that its contents are always written in the upright font shape, regardless of whether the surrounding text is in typeset upright or in italics (as will often be the case in theorem-like environments).

Comment: in doing `\label{eq\arabic{myeqn}}` you lose a large part of the benefit of the automatic numbering and cross reference mechanism.

Comment: @mico, actually I use \hypertarget and \href.  I just wanted to demonstrate how to counters and set up numbered labels.